# Change the display based on state from other component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

So I have this `custom collapse` where I switch between 2 styles of displaying based on this `const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);` state. Then I use this `custom collapse` on another component where after I click on a button I will want to change to another style of display which is the `3rd style of display`. How exactly do I get the state then change it on the original component?
Here's the custom collapse in **./CustomCollapse.js**

```js
const CustomCollapse = (props) => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  return (
    <StyledCollapse onChange={() => setDisabled(prev => !prev)}>
      <AntCollapse.Panel
        header={props.header}
        key="1"
        showArrow={false}
        bordered={false}
        extra={
          <span>
            <span style={{ color: "#0076de", float: "right" }}>
            // Here's where I wanna add the 3rd style
              {disabled ? <div id={styles.themeBox}><p>+10</p></div> : <img src={arrowDownIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', marginLRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} />}
            </span>
          </span>
        }
      >
        {props.children}
      </AntCollapse.Panel>
    </StyledCollapse>
  );
};
```

Here's where I want to change the state in **./FollowTelegram.js**:

```js
import AntCollapse from './CustomCollapse';

  let [followed, setFollowed] = useState(false);
  const setFollowed = () => {
    setFollowed(prev => !prev)
  } 
// {...other code}

<AntCollapse id={styles.telegramHeader1} header="Follow XXX on Telegram Announcement Channel">
          <Row type='flex' align='middle' justify='center'>
            <Button href={links[0]} target="_blank" style={buttonStyle1} onClick={() => setClicked(false)}>
              <Icon type="link" style={{ color: '#fff' }} theme="outlined" />
              Subscribe
            </Button>
          </Row>
          <span className={styles.greyLine}> </span>
          <Row type='flex' align='middle' justify='center'>
           //Here's where I wanna change followed to true
            <Button onClick={setFollowed} style={buttonStyle2} disabled={clicked}>Continue</Button> 
            <Button type='text' style={{color:'#EB7B59', border:'#f7f7f7', background:'#f7f7f7',height: "2em", fontSize:'16px', margin:'10px 0 0 10px'}}>Cancel</Button>
          </Row>
        </AntCollapse>
```

But how can I pass the state to **./CustomCollapse** to know and change the style?

Comment: I can't see that you are using CustomCollapse in another component!!

Comment: please, keep the question as it's, and don't use answers to update it to not confuse anyone else who wants to answer unless you have extra details you want to add. or mention that you have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the disabled value to the child component (CustomCollapse ) by adding a property.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const CustomCollapse = (props) => {
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setDisabled(props.isDisabled)
    }, [props.isDisabled])

    return (
        <StyledCollapse onChange={() => setDisabled(prev => !prev)}>
            <AntCollapse.Panel
                header={props.header}
                key="1"
                showArrow={false}
                bordered={false}
                extra={
                    <span>
                        <span style={{ color: "#0076de", float: "right" }}>
                            // Here's where I wanna add the 3rd style
                            {disabled ? <div id={styles.themeBox}><p>+10</p></div> : <img src={arrowDownIcon} alt="" style={{ height: '1.2em', marginLRight: '10px', width: 'auto', objectFit: 'contain', float: 'left' }} />}
                        </span>
                    </span>
                }
            >
                {props.children}
            </AntCollapse.Panel>
        </StyledCollapse>
    );
};
```

and in the parent component

```
import AntCollapse from './CustomCollapse';

    //inside your parent component

    let [followed, setFollowed] = useState(false);
    const [disabledCollapse, setDisabledCollapse] = useState(true)
    // {...other code}
    const toggleDisabledCollapse = () => {
        setDisabledCollapse(prev => !prev)
    }
    return <AntCollapse isDisabled={disabledCollapse}  id={styles.telegramHeader1} header="Follow XXX on Telegram Announcement Channel">
        <Row type='flex' align='middle' justify='center'>
            <Button href={links[0]} target="_blank" style={buttonStyle1} onClick={() => setClicked(false)}>
                <Icon type="link" style={{ color: '#fff' }} theme="outlined" />
                Subscribe
            </Button>
        </Row>
        <span className={styles.greyLine}> </span>
        <Row type='flex' align='middle' justify='center'>
               //Here's where I wanna change followed to true
            <Button onClick={toggleDisabledCollapse} href={links[0]} target="_blank" style={buttonStyle2} disabled={clicked}>Continue</Button>
            <Button type='text' style={{ color: '#EB7B59', border: '#f7f7f7', background: '#f7f7f7', height: "2em", fontSize: '16px', margin: '10px 0 0 10px' }}>Cancel</Button>
        </Row>
    </AntCollapse>
```

Comment: I just updated the code you just included. But it doesn't work. I added `setFollowed` in **./FollowTelegram** and in the `button` is where I would want to send the `state: followed` to **./CustomCollapse** . How exactly do I do that? Also, am i doing it write on this line: `{followed ? <div id={styles.themeBox}><p>+10</p></div> : <img src={tickIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', marginLRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} />}` ?

Comment: you are not passing isFollowed to AntCollapse in the parent component. please check my code again. you need to pass `isFollowed ={followed}` in AntCollapse

Comment: to be like this `<AntCollapse isFollowed={followed}  id={styles.telegramHeader1} header="Follow XXX on Telegram Announcement Channel">`

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Comment: You are welcome, Glad to help.